# ComboBox in UI5 does not display ValueState

Tags: sapui5

ComboBox is not showing state like Error, Warning with highlight around the borders. But it does change the state. For example, if it is error state, and if I try to enter new value in combobox, it will show that "invalid Entry" tip near the box. But the box borders are never highlighted in red. Below is the code:

***XML.view***

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout">
<Dialog id......>

    <ComboBox id="combo1" change="cChanged" items="{path: '/results'}">
                <items>
                    <core:Item key="{ID}" text="{Name}"/>
                </items>
    </ComboBox>
</Dialog>
```

***Controller.js***

```
cChanged: function(oEvent) {
        var newval = oEvent.getParameter("newValue");
        var key = oEvent.getSource().getSelectedItem();

        if (newval !== "" && key === null) {
            sap.ui.getCore().byId("combo1").setValueState("Error");
            oEvent.getSource().setValue("");
            sap.m.MessageToast.show("Please select from existing IDs")
            flag = false;
        } else {
            oEvent.getSource().setValueState('None');
        }
```

Comment: Kindly share the screenshot for better understanding..

Comment: Kindly check if any custom CSS is overriding the default CSS. Also as mentioned by @fabiopagoti no need to use `sap.ui.getCore().byId("combo1")` as the event is trigger from the control only. Just use `oEvent.getSource()` which will return the instance of the `ComboBox`. Even check the condition `if (newval !== "" && key === null) {` new value will always exist unless you have an empty list item.

Answer (score 0):

You can also access `combo1` control instance by using `oEvent.getSource()` event OR use [**byId()** from the `sap.ui.core.Fragment`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Fragment/methods/sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId) class and not `sap.ui.getCore().byId()`

Also, if you are writing a logic only to validate if what the user input in the combobox is a valid item, consider replacing your `ComboBox` by the [sap.m.Select](https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.m.Select) control.

Both `ComboBox` and `Select` has same look and feel, but `Select` does not allow a manual input. It can also have an empty option if you use the property [**forceSelection**](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.Select/methods/setForceSelection)